# SVG <mask> tag required for Firefox but appears to break CSS mask in Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, svg, mask

I'm trying to mask content with an external SVG image like so:

```
#homepage-banner .desktop-slider.masked {
  -webkit-mask:url(news-panel-mask.svg) left top no-repeat; /* Chrome/Safari (Webkit) */
  mask: url(news-panel-mask.svg#mask); /* Firefox */
}
```

The news-panel-mask.svg file has the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="1170px" height="494px" viewBox="0 0 1170 494" enable-background="new 0 0 1170 494" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path fill="white" d="M1170.001,494V0h-352v141.605c0,2.2-0.521,5.274-2.075,6.832l-21.725,21.393c-1.554,1.557-3.2,4.631-3.2,6.832v131.692
    c0,2.2,2.021,5.274,3.575,6.832l20.975,21.393c1.554,1.557,2.45,4.631,2.45,6.831V494H1170.001z"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

This works on Firefox, but I need to remove the `<defs>` and `<mask>` tags in the svg file to get it to work on Chrome. Is there a way i can fix this so I can use the same svg file for both browsers?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did a few more searches on SO and found a workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745742/problems-with-mask-in-firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As linked in my comment above, the solution is to use separate paths for each browser in the .svg file:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1170px" height="494px" viewBox="0 0 1170 494" enable-background="new 0 0 1170 494" xml:space="preserve">

  <!-- Webkit -->
  <path fill="white" d="M1170.001,494V0h-352v141.605c0,2.2-0.521,5.274-2.075,6.832l-21.725,21.393c-1.554,1.557-3.2,4.631-3.2,6.832v131.692
c0,2.2,2.021,5.274,3.575,6.832l20.975,21.393c1.554,1.557,2.45,4.631,2.45,6.831V494H1170.001z"/>

  <!-- Firefox -->
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path fill="white" d="M1170.001,494V0h-352v141.605c0,2.2-0.521,5.274-2.075,6.832l-21.725,21.393c-1.554,1.557-3.2,4.631-3.2,6.832v131.692
c0,2.2,2.021,5.274,3.575,6.832l20.975,21.393c1.554,1.557,2.45,4.631,2.45,6.831V494H1170.001z"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

</svg>
```

Comment: It is possible to re-use the first `path` element inside the `mask` with `<use xlink:href="#id-of-path"/>` (at least according to spec).

Comment: @ErikDahlström Hmmm... the `<use>` tag doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @gmaggio please post a new question with more details, seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/2XhEb/ (firefox nightly).

Comment: In the fiddle above you can see the mask is present in FF (72, Mac) but not on Chrome (79)