# Firefox gradient as mask

Tags: css, firefox, mask, linear-gradients

Good day everyone, I'm adopting [this](http://codepen.io/socialblogsite/pen/FphBJ) sample to cross-browser solution

I've allready adopted everything except one thing on line 122:

```
-webkit-mask: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 49%, #000 53%);
```

Seems like FF can't generate gradient as mask.
I've tried [this](http://www.visualcsstools.com/) generator for generating base64 svg and applying this as mask, but no success, either i don't understand something on svg generation.

Can anyone point me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG <mask> tag required for Firefox but appears to break CSS mask in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600608/svg-mask-tag-required-for-firefox-but-appears-to-break-css-mask-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not understand rules for webkit. Try "-moz-linear-gradient" for gradient generation and "mask" for masking. Although Firefox can't use gradients for masking, but needs svg masks. Find some information e.g. in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600608/svg-mask-tag-required-for-firefox-but-appears-to-break-css-mask-in-chrome) post.