# SVG mask for SVG element on SVG file in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I have a question. I have a svg file(content a that part):

```
<mask id="mask">
<path d="m 86.9,1.2 71.5,41.3 c 3,1.7 4.9,5.4 5.1,8.9 l 0,82.6 c 0,3.4 -2.3,7 -5.1,8.9 l -71.5,41.3 c -3,1.7 -7.2,1.5 -10.2,0 L 5.1,142.8 C 2.1,141.1 0.2,137.4 0,133.9 L 0,51.4 C 0,48 2.3,44.4 5.1,42.5 L 76.7,1.2 c 2.9,-1.7 7.1,-1.5 10.2,0 l 0,0 z" fill="#fff"/>
</mask>
```

CSS:

```
-webkit-mask: asset_url("file.svg#mask");
 mask: asset_url("file.svg#mask");
```

and apply to svg in html:

```
%svg
  %image
```

Its work in firefox, but dosn`t work in chrome.
What i doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600608/svg-mask-tag-required-for-firefox-but-appears-to-break-css-mask-in-chrome     refer this.. this might help you

Comment: YES, it`s help for me! Thanks. And one more question: how i can change this svg path to relative points? May be u now =)