# How can I apply a mask from an inline SVG that will work in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to clip my element using an SVG shape which is defined in the same HTML file (an inline SVG).

It works with `clip-path`:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: url("#c");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <clippath id="c">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
      </clippath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```

But when using a mask, although this works fine in Firefox, it applies no masking in Chrome:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  mask: url("#m");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <mask id="m">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="white" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Searching around ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600608)), it seems as though Chrome does not expect the mask to refer to a definition, but instead to an entire image. Is there a way to refer to an entire image if it has been inlined, though? Or, is there anything else I could do to apply a mask from an inline element?

Comment: @Kaiido it's not a duplicate since my question is about an inline SVG; the other question is explicitly about an external file, and that distinction is the whole point of the question.

Comment: Yep sorry just tried it out and saw that it won't work for inlined ones... Do you hope for a non-js solution?

Comment: @Kaiido I'm open to anything, but non-js is probably preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an ugly js solution, which will

- grab the content of your `<mask>`,
- copy it in a new svg element <sub>(luckily chrome doesn't need width and height)</sub>,
- convert it to a data-URI and set it to the `-webkit-mask-image` property.

```js
const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
const mask = document.querySelector("mask");
svg.innerHTML = mask.innerHTML;
const markup = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
const url = `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,${ encodeURIComponent(markup) }`;
const div = document.getElementById('mask-me');
div.style.webkitMaskImage = `url('${ url }')`;
```

```css
#mask-me {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  /**
    This will be overidden by -webkit-mask-image even in Firefox.
    We could have avoided it with a CSS variable, e.g
    -webkit-mask-image: var(--workaround-url);
    but Safari acts in all ways as if they did support inline SVG as mask,
    when they don't.
    So, for them, we have to use the workaround everywhere...
  mask-image: url(#m);
  **/
}
```

```html
<div id="mask-me">
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <mask id="m">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="white" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

For the ones needing the `mask-mode: luminance` feature, you need to do it manually in the generated SVG image through a `<feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha"/>`:

```js
const svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
const svg = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
// create a <filter><feColorMatrix type="luninanceToAllpha"/>
const alpha = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "feColorMatrix");
alpha.setAttribute("type", "luminanceToAlpha");
const filter = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "filter");
filter.setAttribute("id", "alpha");
filter.append(alpha);
svg.append(filter);
// apply the filter on all the <mask> content
const g = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "g");
g.setAttribute("filter", "url(#alpha)");
// luminanceToAlpha disregards semi-transparent pixels,
// so we add a black background to have no such thing 
const bg = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
bg.setAttribute("width", "100%");
bg.setAttribute("height", "100%");
g.append(bg);

var mask = document.querySelector('mask').cloneNode(true);
g.append(...mask.children);
svg.append(g);

const markup = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
const url = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8," + encodeURIComponent(markup);
const div = document.getElementById("mask-me");
div.style.webkitMaskImage = `url('${ url }')`;
```

```css
.border {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#mask-me {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  /** Safari doesn't really support mask-image using inline SVG either...
    mask-image: url(#m);
    mask-mode: luminance;
  **/
}
```

```html
<div id="mask-me">
  <svg width="0">
    <defs>
      <mask id="m">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="white" />
        <rect x="90" y="90" width="20" height="20" fill="black" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Neat! Though you can now remove the `mask:` line in the `#mask-me` CSS rule.

Comment: @Oak nope, it can still be needed for FF and others that don't know about `webkitMaskImage` (btw, we should probably do a check for it before-hand but I'll let it as an exercise for readers : `webkit` is becoming the standard prefix for everyone)

Comment: @kaiido thanks for the solution! However it doesn't support percentage values, right? When I give it plain integer values, it works but fails on percentage ones. Tried giving viewBox or with/height to the generated svg but all are ignored.

Comment: @kaiido moreover, I don't think negative areas in the mask (fill=black) are supported in this way.

Comment: @alexsmith percentage values work for me. However the inline version in Firefox is a bit weird since they'll make it relative to the size of the parent <svg> in case it's not 0. Through the SVG image it will be relative to the target size. And I added a solution to handle the `mask-mode: luminance`.

Comment: @Kaiido that's great. thank you. The second code snippet preview, it seems the red circle has lost anti-alias effect. (the first one is smoother) Is that correct?

Comment: @alexsmith oh I fear it is indeed... Looks like luminanceToAlpha disregards semi-transparent pixels... which sounds weird to me.

Comment: @alexsmith could fix it by prepending a black rectangle in the background.

Comment: @Kaiido Perfect. I want to upvote you more :)  btw I think the css property is `mask-type` . Your answer says `mask-mode`

Comment: No, it's mask-mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-mode `mask-type` was for SVG I think, but I doubt any browser ever implemented it.

Comment: @Kaiido yes it is `mask-mode` in Firefox/Safari. In Webkit I only have `mask-type` with 'luminance` value.

Comment: Yes Chrome doesn't implement mask, that's the whole problem and the mere reason for this question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked Chrome doesn't support the `mask` property. [It only supports `mask-image`.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks)

I imagine that is still the case.

Comment: `mask` is a shorthand, `mask-image` is included in `mask`, however, it seems that chrome still needs `-webkit-` prefix. But even though, referencing an SVGMaskElement doesn't work.